# I have opened a form using Form2 fm2 = new Form2(); how do i hide the 1st Form?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, if-statement, show-hide, showdialog

I have written this when I made a quiz.

I declare that if `radioButton1` is checked you get 1 point and it shows in the next form. As it is now my program opens up a new form for every question and doesn't hide the old ones.

```
Form2 fm2 = new Form2();
if (radioButton1.Checked)
{
    int poäng = 1;
    fm2.lblAntalPoäng.Text = poäng.ToString();
    fm2.ShowDialog();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Form1.Hide();
```

If you're in the class itself then:

```
this.Hide();
```

Comment: Thanks, the this.Hide(); worked.
But the Form1.Hide(); didn't

Answer (score 1):

```
 Form a = new Form();            
 this.Hide(); // If you are in Class Form b
 a.ShowDialog();
 this.Show(); // this will enable the Parent (Hidden)form to reappear.
```